# Select columns in PostgreSQL from an array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, list

Let’s say I have the following queries:

```
SELECT
    A, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k
INTO test
FROM source
WHERE ...

SELECT
    A, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k
INTO test1
FROM source
WHERE …

SELECT
    A, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k
INTO test2
FROM source
WHERE …
```

Is there any way I could place A, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k into a list or an array that I could then pass in select?

Something like this:

```
myColumns = [A, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k]

SELECT
    myColumns
INTO test2
FROM source
```

Comment: You can simply construct the SELECT dynamically by string concatenation.

Comment: Unrelated, but: The use of  `select ... into new_table` is discouraged in favour of the standard compliant `create table new_table as select ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using psql, You cen set a variable like below:

```sql
\set cols a,b,c
```

then use it:

```sql
SELECT :cols FROM test;
```